# Congruence of Type Level Nats in Haskell

Tags: haskell, proof, type-level-computation

I am trying to implement a version of Braun Tree in Haskell, which requires me to prove this fact about `Nat`s

> If `n :~: m`, then `n + 1 :~: m + 1`

However, I am failing to fill the `undefined` below. I tried `Refl`, but the type system complains.

```
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Type.Equality

sucCong :: ((p :: Nat) :~: (q :: Nat)) -> (p + 1 :: Nat) :~: (q + 1 :: Nat)
sucCong proof = undefined
```

How do I prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern-match on the `proof` to make its statement available to the constraint solver. Then there is only one constructor for the type `(:~:)` so there's not much choice in the rest of the definition anyway.

```
sucCong :: (p :~: q) -> (p+1) :~: (q+1)
sucCong Refl = Refl
```

Comment: So many functions involving `(:~:)` end up having that exact same implementation...